# How blockstack implements identity management?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-key, public-key, identity

Reading https://blockstack.org/posts/blockchain-identity it `states Blockstack is the largest, most popular blockchain identity system, with 50,000 registered identities.` but reading the available papers https://blockstack.org/papers there is no significant detail on how blockstack implements digital identity ?

This is in contrast to uPort who also implement blockchain identity but have a detailed evolving whitepaper on how this is achieved : https://uport.me/library/pdf/whitepaper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

We need to consider the fact that we do not need a blockchain at all, and could be implemented perfectly well using a regular relational database. But while you read through [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-like-build-identity-management-system-using-blockchain-pinto/) that I have recently posted on linkedin, you would not only understand how a blockchain can solve such a use case but also a need to have a technology to solve this.

Comment: welcome to the community :) . Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for post formatting.